# Unable to run headless chrome inside vagrant

Tags: google-chrome, ubuntu, google-chrome-headless

I am trying to run unit tests in headless chrome(version 61). 
I have mentioned the browsers as 'ChromeHeadless' in Karma.config and corresponding script has been added to package.json.

When I run the npm test command inside vagrant(using Ubuntu 64-bit), it gives me this error: 
**FATAL:nss_util.cc(632)] NSS_VersionCheck("3.26") failed. NSS >= 3.26 is required. Please upgrade to the latest NSS, and if you still get this error, contact your distribution maintainer.**

I tried updating the NSS version by running the below command: 
**sudo apt-get install --reinstall libnss3** 
 but still no luck.
Is there anything that I am missing or doing incorrectly?